# Max Connections Per Server

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Does anyone know if there is a way to get more than 6 concurrent connections to the same server using UIWebViews?  I am working on an App that will talk to a server that is recording IP cameras and serving up live views of each one.  I am using a seperate UIWebView for each camera, but once I reach 6 cameras, the next camera just spins until I close out one of the previous 6.  I'm told this is a limit imposed by WEBKIT, but just wondered if there is a work around or a configuration setting somewhere.

Thanks in advance,

Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Rob i tried to find how to get more than 6 connections with no success, the connections are limited by the browser.
for example my iphone admits 6 connections and my Blackberry OS6.0 admits only 5 simultaneous connections.

check with this link you will get the number of supported connections.

[**http://spasche.net/files/parallel_connections/**](http://spasche.net/files/parallel_connections/)

Comment: That's a good link, thanks.  Too bad there doesn't seem to be a way to override that limit for specific applications like the one I am building.